# Use the functions of a vector objects using a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

1).Why did I get this error? What is the correct syntax?

2).Is there a way to write the same code without using the library "vector"?

```
#include <vector>

myClass()
{
    public:
        myClass(int x,int y);
        void doThis()
        {
            //Something
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<myClass>*ex_vector = new std::vector<myClass(5,myClass{10,10});
    ex_vector[0]->doThis(); //Error Here
    delete []ex_vector;
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<myClass>'
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is

```
(*ex_vector)[0].doThis();
```

Also, you should `delete ex_vector;` and not `delete[] ex_vector;` since the type of the `new` was not a raw array type.

However, there's rarely a good reason to `new` a `std::vector`.  Just use a plain object.

Comment: 2).Is there a way to write the same code without using the library "vector"?

Comment: Not easily, since `myClass` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: Vote up for the comment on preferring plain object over pointers. Note that if you are really desperate for pointers, use a smart pointer rather than a raw one.

Comment: Wishing I can add it. The point is that I have to deallocate memory in just end up using the vector.